# How to remove 00:00:00.000 from a datetime type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I print it:

```
PRINT convert(date,GETDATE())
```

Output:

```
2017-05-11
```

I'm creating a table with the default value of the current date, I don't want it to display the 00:00:00.000

```
 CREATE TABLE USER_ACCOUNTS
(
cod_user int primary key,
Date_ins datetime default convert(date,getdate()) not null,
user_name varchar(20) not null
)
```

Output:

```
2017-05-11 00:00:00.000
```

Even If I remove it by editing the field, It comes back after saving.

Comment: Your field type is a `datetime`. It's a `datetime` so there will be time whether you give it a time or not. If you want a `date`, then make the field type a `date`. If you don't want to "See" the `00:00:00.000` on your `datetime` type field, then CAST it to a date when you SELECT from the table.

Comment: Let me guess: you get data from DB in C# or another general purpose language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `date` type instead of `datetime`

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ACCOUNTS
(
cod_user int primary key,
Date_ins date default getdate() not null,
user_name varchar(20) not null
)
```

Side note, `user_name` is a SQL Server built-in function, and you should avoid using it as a column name.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Date` datatype instead of `Datetime`

Answer (score 2):

You also can select format like `mm/dd/yyyy` use :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)
```

Or  `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
```